# Which SQL paradigm to use when grouping counts by type?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, count, django-orm

Let's say I have a database with data from a pizza shop in it. I keep track of customers and their orders via two tables: `customer` and `orders`. `orders` has a FK to `customer` so that I can easily see which orders belong to which customer.

I can count all of the customer's orders like this:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    COUNT(o.id) AS order_counts
FROM
    customers AS c,
    JOIN orders ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY
    c.id
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
results = [
{
  “customer_number”: 1,
  “order_counts”: 5
},
{
  “customer_number”: 2,
  “order_counts”: 10
}]
```

However, what if I want to "explode" the order_counts results to show me all the individual pizza types, and then count those types? I would add a new table called `pizzas` which has a `name` column, and then get my results to look like this:

```
results = [
{
  “customer_number”: 1,
  “counts”: {
    “Hawaiian”: 2,
    “Meat Lovers”: 2,
    "Four Cheese": 1
  }
},
{
  “customer_number”: 2,
  “counts”: {
    “Hawaiian”: 5,
    “Meat Lovers”: 5,
    "Four Cheese": 0
  }
}]
```

Which SQL principals/paradigms would I need to leverage to achieve this? I suspect I need a subquery and/or a nested GROUP BY statement.

Bonus Question: is this possible in the Django ORM, or is this something which hits the ORM's limitations pretty quickly?

Comment: Bonus answer: Yes, with the help of DRF you could easily achieve this. You just need to modify the serializer for that foreign key, by default it will only pass the id of the related object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want that kind of nested output, then you might as well generate JSON directly from the database:

```
select
    c.id customer_id,
    sum(no_pizzas) no_orders,
    jsonb_object_agg(p.name, o.cnt_pizza) counts
from customers AS c,
inner join (
    select customer_id, pizza_id, count(*) cnt_pizza
    from orders o 
    group by customer_id, pizza_id 
) o on c.id = o.customer_id
inner join pizza p  on p.id = o.pizza_id
group by c.id
```

This produces column `counts` as a json object with pizza names as keys and pizza count as value. As a bonus, you still get the total count of orders in column `no_orders`.

If you want to take in account customers with no orders, use `left join`s:

```
select
    c.id customer_id,
    coalesce(sum(no_pizzas), 0) no_orders,
    jsonb_object_agg(p.name, o.cnt_pizza) counts
from customers AS c,
left join (
    select customer_id, pizza_id, count(*) cnt_pizza
    from orders o 
    group by customer_id, pizza_id 
) o on c.id = o.customer_id
left join pizza p  on p.id = o.pizza_id
group by c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The resulting result may contain multiple customer ids, but the numbers are specific for pizzas.

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    COUNT(o.id) AS order_counts,
    p.name
FROM
    customers AS c,
    JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer_id
    JOIN pizzas p ON p.id = o.pizzas_id
GROUP BY
    c.id,
    p.name
```

Comment: I think we'd want to COUNT pizza.id's in this case, right?

Comment: it does not matter :) you can put COUNT(*) , COUNT(p.id)